# Kill all instances of a process except oldest (1st) instance (vbscript)

Tags: vbscript, process, wmi

I'm creating this code to aid in a bigger process I've developed.  This piece will help me to automate it.  Assuming you have opened at least 2 ie windows, the first section below finds the time the 1st was opened and set it to a variable "strReturn".  This is basically the time with the colons removed. I removed the colons for an easier number comparison. Since it seems to loop through these in order, I have it immediately exit the FOR statement since the first is all I care about.

Then, the second statement, which was built to kill ALL instances of a process, I attempted to modify to only kill the one that matches the time in the variable.  However, it does nothing...  I'm sure I'm implementing it incorrectly.  I've bolded the parts I've modified from the original..well, attempted to bold - you'll see asterisks...haha.  Is it clear where I'm going wrong?  TIA

```
'=============================================================
'Finds time first instance of iexplore process was started

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'iexplore.exe'")

For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    dtmStartTime = objProcess.CreationDate
    strReturn = replace(split(WMIDateStringToDate(dtmStartTime), " ")(1), ":", "")

wscript.echo strReturn
exit for
Next

'.............................................................
Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmStart)
    WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmStart, 5, 2) & "/" & _
        Mid(dtmStart, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmStart, 4) _
            & " " & Mid (dtmStart, 9, 2) & ":" & _
                Mid(dtmStart, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmStart, _
                    13, 2))
End Function
'=============================================================


'(Supposed to) Kill every instance of iexplore.exe except the instance matching the start time in strReturn variable (1st instance).

KillProc "iexplore.exe" 

Sub KillProc( myProcess )     

Dim blnRunning, colProcesses, objProcess     

blnRunning = False

Set colProcesses = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery( "Select * From Win32_Process", , 48 )     

    For Each objProcess in colProcesses 

        If LCase( myProcess ) = LCase( objProcess.Name ) **and strReturn < replace(split(WMIDateStringToDate(dtmStartTime), " ")(1), ":", "")** Then 'Confirm process is running

        blnRunning = True 'Get exact case for the actual process name            

        myProcess  = objProcess.Name 'Kill process             

        objProcess.Terminate()        

        End If    

    Next    

    If blnRunning Then         

        Do Until Not blnRunning            

        Set colProcesses = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery( "Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = '"& myProcess & "'" )            

        WScript.Sleep 1000 'Wait 1 second             

        If colProcesses.Count = **1** Then 'Exit loop (changed from 0 to 1)               

        blnRunning = False             

        End If         

        Loop       

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.  I was overthinking it, as I tend to do...

```
'=============================================================
'Finds time first instance of iexplore process was started

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'iexplore.exe'")

For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    dtmStartTime = objProcess.CreationDate
    strReturn = replace(split(WMIDateStringToDate(dtmStartTime), " ")(1), ":", "")

exit for
Next

For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    dtmStartTime = objProcess.CreationDate
    strReturn1 = replace(split(WMIDateStringToDate(dtmStartTime), " ")(1), ":", "")

If strReturn <> strReturn1 then
objProcess.Terminate()
end if
Next

'.............................................................
Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmStart)
    WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmStart, 5, 2) & "/" & _
        Mid(dtmStart, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmStart, 4) _
            & " " & Mid (dtmStart, 9, 2) & ":" & _
                Mid(dtmStart, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmStart, _
                    13, 2))
End Function
'=============================================================
```